# How to set the timeout of request sended by ClientResource in Restlet Framework

Tags: java, restlet, clientresource

I'm using the Restlet framework and specifically the class `ClientResource` to send HTTP request to a server through its own `get()`, `post()`, `put()` and `delete()` methods. Since sometimes the server is offline and therefore unreachable, I would like to set a smaller timeout than the default. How can I do it?

At the moment I've tried in this way with no success:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(uri);

Context context = new Context();
context.getParameters().add("maxIoIdleTimeMs", "0");
context.getParameters().add("ioMaxIdleTimeMs", "0");
context.getParameters().add("socketTimeout", "1000");

cr.setNext(new Client(context, Protocol.HTTP));
cr.setRetryOnError(false);

...

Representation r = cr.get();
```

The result is the same of the default case, that is a timeout of about 60-90 seconds before the connection error exception is returned from the `get()` method. My purpose is to anticipate it.

Comment: Did you try setting `readTimeout`?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps you can try Mashape Unirest library instead?

Comment: @xybrek I can't because this would mean having to change many things in my project. Anyway, this is not a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

To set the timeout properly:

```
Component c = new Component();
Client client = c.getClients().add(Protocol.HTTP);
client.getContext().getParameters().add ( "socketTimeout", "10" );
Response resp = client.handle(new Request(Method.GET, "https://swapi.co/api/people/1/"));
System.out.println("Output: " + resp.getEntity().getText());
```

This code will throw a *timeout exception* as what you needed, increase the `socketTimeout` to at least 1000 to be able to retrieve the test API JSON response.

Also, these versions was used:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```